# How to download a csv file and store contents in an object

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a csv file that i need to download and display in a table.
What i am trying to do is download the file from a server and convert its contents into an object in angular6.

for example i have a file in http://example.com/myFile.csv

But Im unable to do so, What is the correct way to do it?

thanks to anyone who answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to download the file from serve. you can write a function in service using http.

```
this.http.get('assets/file.csv', {responseType: 'text'})
.subscribe(
    data => {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error => {
        console.log(error);
    }
);
```

Then you can read each line of csv file and save them in object/array.